# PC Safari Dropdown Site List

Tags: safari

When I use Safari, I haven't found a drop down list like you have on the IE address bar. In IE you can dropdown this list and choose sites.

In Safari I haven't found such dropdown list. Is it avaliable? How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

i never really use this option in browsers, but i was curious because i remember this feature in older times with IE and kind of assumed it would be in a browser.

it seems like your best alternative is to use bookmarks for pages, although i understand the functionality is kind of different.

you can add the bookmarks under the address bar, or put a button that brings up your 'top sites' next to it.

its not under 'preferences' its under, like 'view' and 'customize toolbar' or something like it.

sorry, but i just dont see that feature in safari